# Why can DFS trees not contain cross edges

Tags: graph-theory, depth-first-search

While ding a depth first search, why is it necessary that there are no cross edges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because if there are cross edges it's no longer a tree (a tree cannot contains cycles).

Any tree with n nodes contains n-1 edges. If you're adding an edge, any edge (cross, back etc) you now have n edges. The two nodes you've just connected by adding this edge already had a path between them (because there's a path between any two nodes in a tree) and by adding this edge you closed a circle. So now the graph is no longer a tree.

Comment: @NelsonMenezes I tried to add an explanation - hope it'll be clearer now